# Maintain client side sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies

We have a web application developed using NodeJS and Plain Vanilla Javascript frontend.

Currently, we have a version of the software with authentication/sessions for one kind of users. 
We are developing a second version without authentication or server-side sessions. Is there a way to keep a session on the client-side (Using cookies or something?) so that the user's settings can be saved for some time until the cookie/or something else expires?

We just need a conceptual understanding of how I can proceed, as I was not finding anything relevant online regarding the same.

Thanks! Any inputs will be valuable.

Comment: You can use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for that; it allows you to save arbitrary strings.

Comment: Any examples of its usage in detail? and on how it works?

Comment: Great. Thanks anyways!!

Comment: It's not complex or anything, just do `localStorage.setItem("userdata", JSON.stringify(userData));` and restore using `const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));`